# Как залить в код свой датасет

Tags: python, база-данных, нейронные-сети

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KZEXBI4xIDAa-Fk59b_NhiFDASrzaER/view?usp=sharing
Это мой измененный код.
Но там не мой датасет и я не знаю как сделать и залить свой датасет.
Я везде искал как это сделать и нигде не мог найти.
Пожалуйста помогите мне с моей проблемой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно открыть в JupyterNotebook и отредактировать.

Данные подключаются в этой части кода:

```
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
```

Меняете пути на свои (это же обработка изображений).

```
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]
```

Comment: А что и в какой строке подключать и изменять?

Comment: в папке test_images

Comment: туда нужно подключить мой дататсет чтобы переобучить модель?

Comment: Обученная модель находится в этом файле. Возможно у вас есть полное задание, тогда будет более ясно, что конкретно править

Comment: я хотел прогу которая определяет лица в реальном времени по собственному датасету

Comment: Тогда эта программа вам не подойдет так как она определяет на основе уже созданной модели. frozen_inference_graph.pb